# Error porting my app to Google TV

Tags: android, porting, google-tv

Im currently trying to port my somewhat complicated application to Google TV. I can deploy, but i'm getting a **"Portrait mode is not available for this application. Press any key to exit."** error, which is quite odd since I don't explicitly specify using portrait mode anywhere in the manifest. I can dismiss the error, the app then shows for a second seemingly correct, and then the app gets dismissed.

Of course I've read up on [the Google TV page](http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_androidmanifest.html) manifest reference, which states that every activity needs to have `screenOrientation="unspecified"` (which is the default). I've tried to explicitly define this at each of the activities I have, but still gives me the same error.

Tried adding these to the manifest as well (to no effect):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="com.google.android.tv" android:required="true"/>
```

Now my question is; what am I missing here? What can I check in order to figure out what goes wrong?

Comment: What directory are your layouts in?  Perhaps they require Portrait?

Comment: @Les i had thought of that; the only layouts i've got specifically for portrait are for my widgets on tablet; funny thing is the widgets do work. I removed those directories (layout and drawables), but to no avail. I do still have specific Landscape directories, and given the fact that my widgets show specific landscape layout that seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be setting the requested orientation in code somewhere using:

```
Activity.setRequestedOrientation(..)
```

Perhaps you can provide your manifest?

Comment: Thanks, that actually was it :) I had one of those because I used a little trick having a values.xml for different specifications, such that I can do this if it is running on a phone: `if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.lockOrientation))  this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` I guess I'll have to find a solution to that problem, or I need a specific APK for GoogleTV, which i don't like to do.

Comment: rock on, glad to help. You can use the multiple APK support if you need to that's why it's there. Although I agree with you, it seems like a bit of a "cop out" :)